# operator overload taking initializer list as parameter

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, visual-studio-2017, initializer-list

I wanted to find a convenient way to check if a value was in a set of values. If I create a simple function like the following, everything works well:

```
bool IsIn(const int& value, initializer_list<int> initializerList)
{
    vector<int> v(initializerList);
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), value) != v.end();
}

bool MyFunction()
{
    return IsIn(1, { 1,2,3 });
}
```

if I now turn this function into a more user-friendly operator >>, i get an error **C2059: syntax error: '{'**

```
bool operator >>(const int& value, initializer_list<int> initializerList)
{
    vector<int> v(initializerList);
    return find(v.begin(), v.end(), value) != v.end();
}

bool MyFunction()
{
    return 1 >> { 1, 2, 3 };
}
```

I did not find in C++ specification that the use of a initializer list as parameter was limited to "normal" functions. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? (I am using VS2017)

Comment: `Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?` You're doing it wrong...

Comment: `{ 1, 2, 3 }` is not an `std::initializer_list`. It's some untyped thing that depending on context does various other things. `1 >> initializer_list<int>{ 1, 2, 3 }` should work fine.

Comment: Also, this is not a very clear overload to begin with, better stick with the named function.